# reverse the name if it seperate by comma

Tags: r, regex, string

If there is a first and last name is like "nandan, vivek". I want to display as "vivek nandan".

```
n<-("nandan,vivek")
```

result:

```
[1] vivek nandan
```

where first name:vivek

last name:nandan

this is the author name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try using `sub` here:

```
input <- "nankin,vivek"
sub("([^,]+),\\s*(.*)", "\\2 \\1", input)

[1] "vivek nankin"
```

The regex pattern used above matches the last name followed by the first name, in separate capture groups.  It then replaces with those capture groups, in reverse order, separated by a single space.

Comment: Glad to help you :-)

Comment: hello , how to remove space after second name eg: "jyoti paswan " to "jyoti paswan"

Comment: Try using `trimws`, e.g. `trimws("jyoti paswan ")`

Answer (score 0):

An option would be `sub` to capture the substring that are letters (`[a-z]+`) followed by a `,` and again capture the next word (`[a-z]+`).  In the replacement,  reverse the order of the backreferences

```
sub("([a-z]+),([a-z]+)", "\\2 \\1", n)
#[1] "vivek nandan"
```

---

A non-regex option would be to split the string and then `paste` the `rev`ersed words

```
paste(rev(strsplit(n, ",")[[1]]), collapse=" ")
#[1] "vivek nandan"
```

Or extract the `word` and `paste`

```
library(stringr)
paste(word(n, 2, sep=","), word(n, 1, sep=","))
#[1] "vivek nandan"
```

#### data

```
n<- "nandan,vivek"
```